# Stability of linear autonomous systems

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x'=Ax, A\in \mathbb{R^{n,n}}$, be a linear autonomous system. Denote by $\{ \lambda_j\}$ the set of the eigenvalues of $A$. I want to study its stability. There is this following fact that im supposed to use:

> The systen is stable (i.e. all solutions are bounded) if $Re(\lambda _j)\leq 0$ for all $j$ and $g_j=a_j$ if $Re(\lambda _j)=0$.

Where $g_j $ and $a_j$ denote the geometric resp. algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda _j$.

My question is, what if the eigenvectors are complex? How do we "count" the geometric multiplicity then? For example, let $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
   0&2&1\\
   -2&0&2\\
0&0&-3\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Its eigenvalues are $(-3,-2i,2i)$ where $a_j=1$ . Now, to know if its stable or not, i need to calculate the geometric multiplicities of the eigenvalues 2i and -2i. What are they? Is this system stable? Do we count each complex eigenvalue as 1 independent vector or 2 independent vectors, one real and the other complex?

Comment: For matrices with real entries, the geometric/algebraic multiplicities of conjugate (complex) eigenvalues are the same, so it does not matter which eigenvalue you choose. In your example, the geometric and algebraic multiplicity of $2i$ is one, so the system is stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yor matrix $A$ is $3 \times 3$ and $A$ has $3$ different eigenvalues, hence the geometric multiplicities of each eigenvalue $=1.$